Proving $\frac{\sqrt2}2\sec\alpha\sec(\frac{\pi}4-\alpha)=\tan\alpha+\tan(\frac{\pi}4-\alpha)$
I was translating a Euclidean-geometric problem in term of trigonometry, and I have arrived this equation:

$$\frac{\sqrt2}2\sec\alpha\sec(\frac{\pi}4-\alpha)=\tan\alpha+\tan(\frac{\pi}4-\alpha)$$
where, $\alpha\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}4)$.

I want to prove this equality holds. Here is my approach:
Squaring both sides we have:
$$\dfrac12 \sec^2\alpha\sec^2(\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha)=(\tan\alpha+\tan(\frac{\pi}4-\alpha))^2$$
Let, $a=\tan \alpha$ and $b=\tan(\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha)$ we have $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)=2(a+b)^2$.
By substituting $b= \dfrac{1-a}{1+a}$ we have:
$$(1+a^2)\left(1+(\dfrac{1-a}{1+a})^2\right)= 2 \left(a+(\dfrac{1-a}{1+a})\right)^2$$
Multiplying both sides by $(1+a)^2$:
$$(1+a^2)\left((1+a)^2+(1-a)^2\right)= 2\left(a(1+a)+(1-a)\right)^2$$
$$2(a^2+1)^2=2(a^2+1)^2$$
I'm looking for alternative methods to prove the trigonometric equation.

For more information, here is the geometry problem:

$ABCD$ is a square and $\angle GDF=45^{\circ}$ and $DH \perp FG$.
Prove that $DH=AD$.


Where I used $\angle FDC=\alpha$ and assumed the side of the square is $1$. The trigonometric equation is obtained when I applied the cosine rule in $\triangle GDF$ ($GF^2=DG^2+DF^2-2(DG)(DF)\cos(\dfrac{\pi}4)$) and simplified the resulting equation.

Proof Without Words:

The area of the large triangle is equal to the sum of areas of the two sub triangles.

I think it is easier to prove the proposed identity from the RHS to the LHS. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\tan(\alpha) + \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \alpha\right) & = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)} + \frac{1 - \tan(\alpha)}{1 + \tan(\alpha)}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)} + \frac{\cos(\alpha) - \sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\alpha)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)(\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\alpha))}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cos(\alpha)\cos(\alpha - \pi/4)}\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sec(\alpha)\sec\left(\alpha - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!
